# Rotate Apple Map as per user movement

Tags: swift3, ios10, core-location, apple-maps

- Apple Map
- Core Location

I implemented `Apple Map` with `Core Location` and its `delegate` to add pin and its working perfectly but now i am stuck with the issue to :

`Rotate Map as per user movement` ( as user travelling with car moves the different direction , the apple map should move )

I found **Apple Map native** does same work . Here is gif :
[image]

I did find solution yet . Kindly suggest me how to do it ?

**Note ->**

- Don't want to use Google Map
- Don't want to move Pin (annotation view)
- If you want me to update my existing code , i can update again .

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` to your toolbar, it behaves exactly as the button in Maps app and handles all of the magic.

```
    let trackingButton = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: mapView)
    toolbarItems = [trackingButton]
```

Alternatively you could set the `MKUserTrackingMode` but then you're going to run into some handling issues, and a few caveats of doing it this way. Such as resetting the view after user scrolls the map, and not being able to control the zoom level among other things.

```
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.followWithHeading, animated: true)
```

Comment: i dint get , can you add little bit more in it . i want to rotate Map as user moves into different direction not showing any button on map.

Comment: The button adds the functionality you want, try it out.

Comment: i dont want to add any button , i just want to rotate map . no need to add button , since m not using any toolbar item in my application

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Well you could add it to your navigation bar also. Mind if I ask what kind of app this is that requires the map to be rotating at all times without a way to shut it off if it gets dizzying or annoying?

Comment: it will rotate when there is a path to move , like the uber cab suddenly moves into the direction u were